# Cloud-Custodian DynamoDB auto-tag-user exists?

Tags: aws-lambda, cloudcustodian

I am using auto-tag-user policy for EC2 and I want to use that feature for DynamoDB and RDS too.
Is there any way to use like that? I have applied policy below without an error but it does not work

```
policies:
  - name: owner-autotagging-on_table_creation
    resource: dynamodb-table
    mode:
      role: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/administrator
      type: cloudtrail
      events:
        - CreateTable
    filters:
      - "tag:owner": absent
    actions:
      - type: auto-tag-user
        tag: owner
        principal_id_tag: ownerID
```

Answer (score 2):

Lamda function which is created by the custodian is trying to "describe" the table/resource which has been just created, but can't do it, because the table is in "creation state". You can check that in CloudTrail logs events for the Lambda function. 

 Currently, custodian is not checking the state of the table before doing the "Describe" step. A workaround will be to set a small sleep in custodian lambda function before it does the "Describe" step. "Describe" step is required to get the list of existing tags within the table and after that, it applies new tags.

Answer (score -2):

Sleep request has been accepted and merged the main code.

This feature is currently available